# Lambda Group By Max

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have this query.

```
select distinct game_id, max(event_number)  as LatestEvent from Source group by game_id
```

But I would like this converted to its Linq or Lambda equivalent and I havent found a way to do so properly.  Can someone advise.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A sidenote: `DISTINCT` makes no sense in your query. As you group by `game_id` and select `game_id`, the rows are naturally unique. There are no duplicates `DISTINCT` could remove.

Answer (score 7):

```
var q = db.Table
   .GroupBy(x => x.game_id)
   .Select(g => new { game_id = g.Key, LatestEvent = g.Max(x => x.event_number) });
```